# Best scripting language to wrap a Java process in?

Tags: java, scripting, process

I have a Java server process that I normally run in either Windows batch file consoles or in Linux Bash script consoles.   I manage these scripts independently of each other and I wish I had something that was cross platform, more powerful, and easier.

Besides running the java process itself, the scripts need to create files, configure files, read/write .xml config data, prepare databases, etc.

So, which scripting language would be the best for this that would allow the script to go cross platform?

Also, if you have heard of someone doing something similar to this, I would love a link to see the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Groovy would be a great choice. It's syntax is very similar to Java, but it is much more concise (than Java), particularly for the kind of things you need to do in scripts. For example, here's a Groovy script that reads the content of a file:

```
String content = new File("/path/to/file.txt").text
```

That's it! There's no need to put it inside a class or even compile it. Just put the text above in a file named `Script.groovy` and invoke it from the command line using `groovy Script.groovy`.

Also, because Groovy runs on the JVM there should be no cross-platform issues, and you'll already have the necessary runtime installed on all the machines you need to run your scripts on.

Groovy comes with a console that you can use to quickly test out your scripts.

Comment: I decided to go with Groovy.   My skill is in Java programming and so this means I don't need to use a new language.   My server and the configuration is all one language.

Comment: Groovy is a different language than Java, but it's almost a superset, so you can slowly ease yourself into the Groovy-specific features

Comment: Yes, I agree.   So far its going well.  Also, the open source project YAJSW (service wrapper) has Groovy integration.  Altogher I think Groovy was the right choice.

Comment: After more than a week of trying Groovy, I decided to use a pure Java approach using a open source project called One-Jar .  Groovy is still in the back of my mind though... and I still might need it for something.

Answer (score 4):

Edit to actually phrase this as an answer:

Just use Java.

Is there a reason that you can't write that stuff in Java as well, and just have some different functions for the few things that aren't cross-platform?

Second edit is a counter-example. My company has a dev team that writes cross-platform Java code, but the scripts for running/upgrading it are written in .SH and .BAT, depending on if it will be Windows or Unix. So they write it twice, in the lowest-common-denominator for the two target platforms.

Comment: You have a point there. I was considering using Groovy but I am not sure of its ease as a cross platform solution.

Comment: You have to think about your audience. Is Groovy something you can package in your, well, package, or is something that your customer's sysadmins are going to have to install? If your target is servers that run Java, just do it all in Java.

Comment: Java is way too verbose to be used as a scripting language

Comment: 1.- Java is more verbose than a scripting Language 2.- Java can't be use as an "extension language".

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to consider putting the "script" stuff in a Jruby script and then having it invoke your Java apps and libraries when necessary. That would work fairly well. The downside is that you would need to maintain a Jruby runtime on all of your servers.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I a mistaken, but isn't the point of things like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to have a build process in Java itself?  I feel that if you had a standardized Java build process that did these things for you, your batch file, bash script, or the necessary derivatives could be much, much simpler.  Then again, IANAJDNEC (I am not a Java developer, not even close).

Answer (score 0):

We did similar thing by ensuring all machines have cygwin. The scripts becomes more portable.  Now trying to replace the shell scripts with perl scripts.

We also  moved most of the functionality into java code.

If this about managing an environment, I recommend [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) farm. It has many builtin task, you may reduce your scripting effort. One of the main feature is to deploy jdk on all machines transparently and then start java tasks there.